# Converting a looker view file to csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, looker

I am trying to convert a looker view file to csv/xls file, with all the  keys as the column header and the corresponding value as each row.

The end goal here is to dynamically identify the keys and have them as column header.

**VIEW FILE**

```
    view: sf_block_group_facts {
      sql_table_name: DATABLOCKS.ACS.FAST_FACTS ;;

      dimension: logrecno_bg_map_block_group {
        hidden: yes
        type: string
        sql: ${TABLE}.LOGRECNO_BG_MAP_BLOCK_GROUP ;;
      }

  measure: total_population {
    description: "Total Population"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.total_population ;;
  }

  # Household Measures
  measure: housing_units {
    type: sum
    group_label: "Households"
    sql:  ${TABLE}.housing_units ;;
  }

  measure: avg_persons_house {
    type: number
    group_label: "Households"
    label: "Average Persons per Household"
    sql: ${total_population}/NULLIF(${housing_units}, 0) ;;
    value_format_name: decimal_2
  }

  # Income Measures
  measure: aggregate_income {
    hidden: yes
    type: sum
    group_label: "Households"
    sql: ${TABLE}.aggregate_income ;;
  }

  measure: avg_income_house {
    type: number
    group_label: "Households"
    label: "Average Income per Household"
    sql: ${aggregate_income}/NULLIF(${housing_units}, 0) ;;
    value_format_name: usd_0
  }

  # Sex Measures
  measure: female_population {
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.female ;;
    group_label: "Sex"
  }
  measure: male_population {
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.male ;;
    group_label: "Sex"
  }
  measure:  pct_male{
    type: number
    label: "Male % of Population"
    group_label: "Sex"
    sql: ${male_population}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
    value_format_name: percent_2
  }
  measure:  pct_female{
    type: number
    label: "Female % of Population"
    group_label: "Sex"
    sql: ${female_population}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
    value_format_name: percent_2
  }

  # Racial Measures

  measure: white_alone_or_in_combo {
    label: "White Population (Alone or in Combo with Other Races)"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.white_alone_or_in_combo ;;
  }
  measure: black_alone_or_in_combo {
    label: "Black or African American Population (Alone or in Combo with Other Races)"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.black_alone_or_in_combo ;;
  }
  measure: amind_alone_or_in_combo {
    label: "American Indian or Native Alaskan Population (Alone or in Combo with Other Races)"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.amind_alone_or_in_combo ;;
  }
  measure: asian_alone_or_in_combo {
    label: "Asian Population (Alone or in Combo with Other Races)"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.asian_alone_or_in_combo ;;
  }
  measure: nat_haw_alone_or_in_combo {
    label: "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander (Alone or in Combo with Other Races)"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.nat_haw_alone_or_in_combo ;;
  }
  measure: white_non_hisp {
    label: "White, Non-Hispanic Population"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.white_non_hisp ;;
  }
  measure: pct_white {
    label: "White % of Population"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: number
    value_format_name: percent_2
    sql: ${white_alone_or_in_combo}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
  }
  measure: pct_black {
    label: "Black/African American % of Population"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: number
    value_format_name: percent_2
    sql: ${black_alone_or_in_combo}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
  }
  measure: pct_asian {
    label: "Asian % of Population"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: number
    value_format_name: percent_2
    sql: ${asian_alone_or_in_combo}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
  }
  measure: pct_amind {
    label: "American Indian or Native Alaskan % of Population"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: number
    value_format_name: percent_2
    sql: ${amind_alone_or_in_combo}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
  }
  measure: pct_nathaw {
    label: "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander % of Population"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: number
    value_format_name: percent_2
    sql: ${nat_haw_alone_or_in_combo}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
  }
  measure: pct_white_nh {
    label: "White, Non-Hispanic % of Population"
    group_label: "Race"
    type: number
    value_format_name: percent_2
    sql: ${white_non_hisp}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
  }

  measure: hispanic_or_latino {
    label: "Hispanic or Latino Population (Any Race)"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.hispanic_or_latino ;;
    group_label: "Hispanic/Latino"
  }
  measure: pct_hispanic_or_latino {
    label: "Hispanic or Latino % of Population (Any Race)"
    type: number
    sql: ${hispanic_or_latino}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
    group_label: "Hispanic/Latino"
    value_format_name: percent_2
  }
  measure: pct_non_hispanic_or_latino {
    label: "Non-Hispanic, Non-Latino % of Population (Any Race)"
    type: number
    sql: 1-(${hispanic_or_latino}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0)) ;;
    group_label: "Hispanic/Latino"
    value_format_name: percent_2
  }
  measure: pct_white_nh2 {
    label: "White, Non-Hispanic % of Population"
    group_label: "Hispanic/Latino"
    type: number
    value_format_name: percent_2
    sql: ${white_non_hisp}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
  }

  # Age Group Measures

  measure: under_18 {
    label: "Population 17 years and younger"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.under_18 ;;
    group_label: "Age"
  }
  measure: eighteen_to_64 {
    label: "Population 18 to 64 years"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.eighteen_to_64 ;;
    group_label: "Age"
  }
  measure: sixty_five_and_over {
    label: "Population 65 years and older"
    type: sum
    sql: ${TABLE}.sixty_five_and_over ;;
    group_label: "Age"
  }
  measure: pct_under_18 {
    label: "% of Population 17 years and younger"
    type: number
    sql: ${under_18}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
    group_label: "Age"
    value_format_name: percent_2
  }
  measure: pct_18_64 {
    label: "% of Population 18 and 64 years"
    type: number
    sql: ${eighteen_to_64}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
    group_label: "Age"
    value_format_name: percent_2
  }
  measure: pct_65_over {
    label: "% of Population 65 and older"`enter code here`
    type: number
    sql: ${sixty_five_and_over}/NULLIF(${total_population}, 0) ;;
    group_label: "Age"
    value_format_name: percent_2
  }
}
```

**PYTHON SAMPLE CODE**

```
import lkml
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('./test_looker_view.view.lkml', 'r') as file:
    parsed = lkml.load(file)
flat = json_normalize(parsed['views'])
flat.head(3)
```

**Expected output**

The csv file should look like:

```
object_type,name,hidden,type,sql,description,label,view,sql_table_name...
dimension,logrecno_bg_map_block_group,yes,string,${TABLE}.LOGRECNO_BG_MAP_BLOCK_GROUP,null,null,sf_block_group_facts,DATABLOCKS.ACS.FAST_FACTS...
measure,total_population,null,sum,${TABLE}.total_population,Total Population,null,sf_block_group_facts,DATABLOCKS.ACS.FAST_FACTS...
```

However I am unable to flatten and group the inner dictionaries. I want to flatten them dynamically without having to worry about the json keys.

I tried using the record path but its more of hard coding

```
dim_data = json_normalize(data= parsed['views'],record_path=['dimensions'], record_prefix="dim.")
```

This is what I have tried so far. there could be another way to flatten a json data which I might not be looking at but this is how far I have got with trial and error.

Comment: I have edited you post to make it clearer. You are on good track, we have input, expected output and a bit of code. We just miss your question? Is it something wrong with your code, could you tell us more about your issue...

Comment: @jlandercy any luck?

Comment: I cannot load the LKML. Please read [mcve] to complete it: we should be able to run your code at once and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @jlandercy did try saving the the lkml as .view.lkml

Comment: Based on your post, I had to copy paste your file, then save it. Then I read it with `lkml` module but there is an issue with the format. Thus I cannot investigate your `pandas` issue because I have no data to work with. This is why building a [mcve] is crucial. It helps you to get help because we can focus on the real problem instead of trying to make your issue reproducible.